# Getting 400 (bad request) when trying to send a message to slack with webhook URL

Tags: c#, httprequest, slack

I'm trying to send a message to a slack channel in C#. with http request, using Webhook url.
In the get response line' I'm getting 400- bad request.

My  function:

```cs
public void SendSlackAlert(string message, string slackUrl)
{
    try
    {
        var content = $"{{\r\n\"text\":\"{Context}\r\n{message} \"\r\n}}";

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(slackUrl))
        {
            return;
        }
        var httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(slackUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpRequest.Timeout = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalMilliseconds);
        var bytesToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
        httpRequest.ContentLength = bytesToSend.Length;
        using (var requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            requestStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

        var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // return "Error";
    }
}
```

I am transferred to catch with the error, in this line:

```cs
var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

would greatly appreciate any attempt to help.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS (secure).  We site may  require HTTPS and you are sending a non secure request.

Answer (score 0):

I saw [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664174/4351786) that having the encoding set can cause issues with the Slack API.

Instead of setting the Content-Type header along with an encoding, try only setting the Content-Type header to application JSON.

Replace this line:

```
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
```

With this line:

```
httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but the question still warrants a solution as there's very little out there that helps. My guess would be your payload JSON is malformed.

For reference, here's a basic implementation that works for simple plaintext messages. You can expand the serializer to work with more complicated objects and Slack's Context Blocks too.

```
public void SendMessage(string message, string channelWebhook)
{
    try
    {
        var payload = new
        {
            text = message
        };
        var serialisedPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(channelWebhook, new StringContent(serialisedPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to send slack message");
    }
}
```